# Draw Bitmap on Xamarin.Android Canvas

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, canvas, bitmap

I see a lot of examples for android programming in java but very little for Xamarin / C# related.

I'm unable to draw this bitmap on my canvas with the following code (i have highlighted whatever is not working as it should). If something works without a compile-time error, the app stops with a `java null object reference` while debugging and it seems that the compiler hasn't picked up my `green.jpg` resource. Everything else seems to work fine.

**How can I get a simple drawable to display on canvas?**

```
class MyCanvasPath : Android.Views.View /*extends View*/
{
    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    Color myColor = new Color();
    Path myPath = new Path(); //Bitmap bitmap; Resource res;
    private int a,b; 
    //Android.Graphics.Drawables.BitmapDrawable bm;

    public MyCanvasPath(Context context) : base(context) //constructor
    {
        //var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(res, Resource.Drawable.green);
        //var bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(green, 100, 100, 400, 400);
        //var bm = Android.Graphics.Drawables.BitmapDrawable.CreateFromPath("E:\\[project_name]\\Resources\\drawable\\green.jpg");
        int[,] FirstPath; int arrayLength = 0;
        FirstPath = new int[,] { { 200, 350 }, { 70, 80 }, { 90, 40 }, { 10, 40 }, { 50, 80 }, { 0, 350 } };
        arrayLength = FirstPath.Length / 2;
        myPaint.SetARGB(255, 200, 255, 0);
        myPaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.FillAndStroke);
        myPaint.StrokeWidth = 9;
        myPaint.TextSize = 40;
        myPaint.Color = Color.DarkCyan; //drawing pencil for path lines
        myColor = Color.RosyBrown; //not used for path or text, hmm
        myPath.Reset();
        myPath.MoveTo(FirstPath[0, 0], FirstPath[0, 1]);
        for (int tempint = 1; tempint < arrayLength; tempint++)
        { myPath.LineTo(FirstPath[tempint, 0], FirstPath[tempint, 1]); } 

    }//end of constructor for MyCanvasPath

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.DrawColor(myColor);
        b = canvas.Height; a = canvas.Width;
        canvas.DrawText(b.ToString()+" x "+a.ToString(),10,b-50, myPaint);
        canvas.DrawPath(myPath, myPaint);
        //canvas.SetBitmap(Resource.Drawable.green);
        //canvas.DrawBitmap(bm, 100, 100, null);
        //canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap,100,100, myPaint);
    }
}//end of class MyCanvasPath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DecodeResource` method to load the drawable. To make it work however, you must ensure that the image's Build Action is `AndroidResource`. Also, instead of your own `res` object, you need to use `Resources` property of your view:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.green);
```

Now you can draw it as expected:

```
canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap,100,100, null);
```

I have created a simple example repository on GitHub, which uses your code and draws the bitmap, you can [check it out here](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/Stack-Overflow-2018/tree/master/CanvasDrawable).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, @Martin. The 'Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.NullPointerException:' is still there. I have even double-checked the Build Action as well as excluded and re-added the jpeg resource. But without luck. I also tried fixing the warning by initializing 'bitmap' [as null](https://answers.unity.com/questions/60461/warning-cs0649-field-is-never-assigned-to-and-will.html) but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where exactly does the exception happen? On which line?

Comment: When I press F5 to debug, output window shows lots of stuff about mono etc.; then just before the app should display on the device or emulator, vs2015 stops with this exception and highlights the last line 'canvas.DrawBitmap'. Placing the mouse pointer on variable 'bitmap' pops up a little tooltip that shows variable name, pipe sign, null and the 'pin this' icon - all inside that tooltip.

Comment: I would suggest to add a check of `if ( bitmap != null )` before the `DrawBitmap` call. But, please, put a breakpoint right after the `Bitmap.Factory.DecodeResource` call to see if the `bitmap` variable is initialized or not

Comment: I had earlier tried a breakpoint in the `onDraw` call and variable `bitmap` showed null at that point (before posting this question). Now i tried your suggestion, put another breakpoint right after its initialization and it appears fine in the _constructor_. [Here](http://prntscr.com/i0b1fv) is a screenshot of variable `bitmap` in my `onDraw` call where it turns to `null`. Could there be a problem with _scope_ (although i doubt it at this point)?

Comment: Don't you use `var bitmap` in the constructor accidentally?

Comment: I guess that was the problem. Removing `var` solved the problem. Though I didn't see a problem using it as I read a few examples using `var` for Bitmaps while searching the internet. Could you point me to such a documentation where it explicitly prohibits use of `var` in a _constructor_?

Comment: The problem is that you needed to have a variable that persisted from constructor to the Draw method. And you defined a field `Bitmap bitmap`  above the constructor. This has a lifetime the same as the view itself. But inside the constructor the use of `var bitmap` creates a new local variable with the same name, which is valid only in the scope of the constructor. So you set its value but the `bitmap` field is not affected and stays null. When constructor finishes, the local `bitmap` variable goes out  scope. Removing `var` means you don't create new variable and you reuse the existing one.